Import dataset after terraform refactoring
I recently refactored a terraform setup, which consisted of multiple main.tf files in very obscure repository setup.
The requirement was to unify this setup to only have 3 directories left, 1 per environment.
Merging the logic etc. went fine, but I got some serious struggles importing the already existing resources. There are over 1000 resources present, which is fine, but I can't find a way to import them.
From main.tf there are modules called, so terraform show outputs many data blocks.
The problem is, I can't find a way to import data in a fresh terraform state, and I seem to be having a chicken-egg paradoxon, as I need the data to be able to import the resources.
When I try to import for example an aws security group, I can't complete it, as I get the following output from the module:
$ terraform import module.tf_environment.aws_default_security_group.default <ID>


╷
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on ../../modules/environment/vpc.tf line 73, in resource "aws_route" "tgw":
│   73:   for_each = toset(data.aws_route_tables.all.ids)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_route_tables.all.ids is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will
│ identify the instances of this resource.
│ 
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where only the values contain
│ apply-time results.
│ 
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.
╵

Which is totally fine, as I got the ids present in the terraform show output of the former state, but I can't import it as I can't import data.
$ terraform import module.tf_environment.data.aws_route_tables.all <ID>
╷
│ Error: A managed resource address is required. Importing into a data resource is not allowed.

Is there a way to achieve this? I somehow accepted that I either need to manually import the resources or to script a way around it.
But I got the feeling there needs to be a better way of achieving this.
Maybe there is a way to merge multiple states into a new one?
I tried to import the existing resources via
terraform import ADDR ID
with the ADDR and ID from the output of
terraform show

Pretty hard to tell what the issue is, but if you have been working with single resources and moved to using for_each without testing first, that could be the first thing to look into.

data.aws_route_tables.all.ids is a list of string, known only after apply ... All points to issues in your refactor ... you better test that in isolation, you have other issues to address before you can import ... I also will strongly recommend you to use import blocks in code instead of the import command: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import
